# How can I print specific searched lines from a log in to a separate text file?

Tags: batch-file

I have a log, and I'd like to be able to search it for key words, and print lines with those words into a new text document. I know that findstr is something I need to use, but I'm not sure how to do so. The main issue I've had so far is getting the lines to print separately. Each line just overwrites the next, and I haven't even gotten to searching the text yet. I'm stuck. Here is what I have so far:

```
@echo off
for /F "delims=" %%x in (Cheater.txt) do echo %%x > evidence.txt
```

However this doesn't work and doesn't have a search function yet.

Comment: Command Prompt Cheat Sheet - https://winsourcecode.blogspot.com/2019/12/command-prompt-cheat-sheet.html.   `Findstr /c:"Text With Spaces" Cheater.txt >> evidence.txt`. `For` can be used (in place of `findstr`) but easier to use `findstr`. Type `findstr /?`/ `>>` appends to a file versus `>` which overwrites a file.

Comment: You don't need a `for` loop to just extract some lines (see Marks comment) unless you need to post-process (change) them.

Comment: I would recommend, if you're not wanting to perform complex searching, that you use `find.exe` instead of `findstr.exe`. `@%__AppDir__%find.exe /I "Search Terms" 0< "File To Search" 1> "Results Output File"`. To find out the options for each and how to use them, you can do so in the comfort of your own Command Prompt window. `help find` and `help findstr` are the two commands you'll need to do that.